# foreach block on page w/ acf fields

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to add a 'margin' block to make it easier to define what padding goes above or below a block. This is using ACF fields for the user to input a number. The issue I am having is when going responsive the padding should change, i've done this with `calc()` but its overriding the styling on each block based on the last blocks padding.

How can I set this so its for each individual block on the page?

TIA.

```
function render() 
    {  

        $margin = get_field('margin');
    ?>
        <style>
            .margin-block {
                margin-top: <?= $margin; ?>px;
                background: blue;
            }
            @media (max-width: 1199px) {
                .margin-block {
                    margin-top: calc(<?= $margin; ?>px * 0.53);
                }
            }
        </style>
        <section class="margin-block"></section>
    <?php 
    
}
```

Comment: Well you would obviously have to write more specific selectors in your CSS, that target only the element in question. That `.margin-block` selects _all_ elements with that class, and that CSS rules repeating the same selector and setting the same properties will overwrite each other, was that not clear to you from the get-go?

Comment: Maybe you should not write an individual rule for each element to begin with. Use a CSS variable in your stylesheet, and then set that variable via inline style on the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone curious, I came up with a solution that seems to work great by pulling the id of the block and appending it to the class.

```
function render( $block ) 
    {  
        $id = $block['id'];
        $margin = get_field('margin');

        $style_desktop = ".margin-block-{$id} { margin-top: {$margin}px; }";
        $style_mobile = "@media (max-width: 1199px) { .margin-block-{$id} { margin-top: calc({$margin}px * 0.53); } }"
    ?>
    
        <style>
            <?= $style_desktop; ?>
            <?= $style_mobile; ?>
        </style>
        <section class="margin-block-<?= $id; ?>"></section>
    <?php 
    
}
```